# Unable to get Hostname and IP and output to file Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently trying to write my first Python3 program. In my program I am calling upon socket to get the IP and Hostname and write it to a file using a function (See code below). However, whenever I call the function it never outputs the IP or Hostname to the file IP.txt, it only writes the except message.

```
def get_Host_name_IP(): 
    try:
        f = open("IP.txt","w+") 
        host_name = socket.gethostname() 
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name) 
        f.write("Hostname :  ", host_name)
        f.write("IP : ", host_ip)

    except: 
        f.write("Unable to get Hostname and IP")
```

Comment: What does *IP.txt* look like? You should probably output the actual exception being raised, with something like `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: What is the exception that is being raised? That will probably go a long way to answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write()` takes one argument (string), so you need to format your strings properly:

```
def get_Host_name_IP(): 
    try:
        f = open("IP.txt","w+") 
        host_name = socket.gethostname() 
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name) 
        f.write(f"Hostname :  {host_name}\n")
        f.write(f"IP : {host_ip}")
    except: 
        f.write("Unable to get Hostname and IP")
```

Comment: @Ashlee Jones - I think, what you really need is the insight that fictitious and misleading error messages like the one you have here are bad. Better use the construct shown by RoadRunner or `except Exception as e:
         f.write(str(e))`.